# Html parser only want to keep particular things in a particular tag

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I want to parse html data. I want to remove all data that is inside tags I don't care about as well as the tag itself. I only want to keep data that is inside a particular span class. Remove the span tags as well however.

Is there perhaps already a prebuilt script online for this? If not what would be the best way to go about doing it, thanks.

Comment: i suppose it belongs to SO itself.

Comment: I don't even know where to start vinculis. That's why I am asking. Also would prefer a prebuilt script if it exists. It's not something I plan to really do more than once etc

Comment: (1) Get list of span tags (2) for each item in list, check if .className == tgtClassName (3) If so, get the .innerText

Comment: Split the question into individual steps. Then search StackOverflow for them. All of them have been answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, why not? I remeber fondly the time when all the documentation seemed to swirl around in my head, much like a room to a drunkard.

There's a number of different ways you can go about this, I presented just one in my comment above. The 3 ways I can see to do it are:

1. Get list of spans, check for appropriate class, grab text if class is target class.
2. Assume only target spans will have the tgt class. grab list of elements with this class name, get text of all elements in list.
3. Use a DOM function to get list of all spans with the tgt className. Get text of all elements in list.

A quick sample, using the results from a google search-page:

Javascript:

```
// getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClass - both return a NodeList
// it is accessed in the same way as an array - with the [] operators, but it's
// not an array object - this is a function that allows us to still iterate through it
// in much the same way.
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

function grabTextFromSpans()
{
    //
    //  1. - assume elements other than span will possess the target className.
    //       onlty get elements that are (a) a span and (b) have the right className
    var spanList = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var validList = [], stringList = [];

    forEachNode(spanList, function(curItem){ if (curItem.className == 'st') validList.push(curItem);} );

    validList.forEach( function(elem){ stringList.push(elem.innerText);} );
    var mStr = '';
    stringList.forEach(function(elem){mStr += elem + "\n";});
    alert(mStr);


    //
    //  2. - assume only the target elements will possess the target className
    //
    var mStr = '';
    var tgtList = document.getElementsByClassName('st');
    forEachNode(tgtList, function(curElem){mStr += curElem.innerText + "\n";} );
    alert(mStr);


    //
    // 3. - assume that tgt elements are spans and have a specific className
    //
    var mStr = '';
    var tgtList = document.querySelectorAll('span.st');
    forEachNode(tgtList, function(curElem){mStr += curElem.innerText + "\n";} );
    alert(mStr);
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol eid="S-WYUPKzGI7JmAWAr4CwBw" id="rso"><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc" sig="u1z">  <div data-ved="0CCQQkgowAA">  <div data-ved="0CCUQkQowAA"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="http://bebraw.github.com/colorjs/" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNFuHzNJryRAA9QBjqC1250RDZAMCQ','','0CCYQFjAA',null,event)">Colorjs by bebraw</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>bebraw.github.com/colorjs/</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:eSrglCqgBAkJ:bebraw.github.com/colorjs/+&amp;cd=1&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNEm0e9Xr7p0eOh7TWkQ81JoqWQNfQ','','0CCcQIDAA',null,event)">Cached</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS0" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="st">colorjs provides simple API that may be used to create colors (<em>RGBA</em>, <em>HSVA</em>, <em>HSLA</em>) and perform various color related operations (conversions and such).<br></span></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc" sig="kDj">  <div data-ved="0CCkQkgowAQ">  <div data-ved="0CCoQkQowAQ"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="https://github.com/bebraw/colorjs" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNFRF9AfGrmbF5E6IhyKId0ztwA7sQ','','0CCsQFjAB',null,event)">bebraw/colorjs · GitHub</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>https://github.com/bebraw/colorjs</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WtA6gOF2ZqEJ:https://github.com/bebraw/colorjs+&amp;cd=2&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNHqdXwTalbWocgzhnaRA1EKTkyMzQ','','0CCwQIDAB',null,event)">Cached</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS1" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="st">colorjs provides simple API that may be used to create colors (<em>RGBA</em>, <em>HSVA</em>, <em>HSLA</em>) and perform various color related operations (conversions and such).<br></span></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc" sig="PWh">  <div data-ved="0CC4QkgowAg">  <div data-ved="0CC8QkQowAg"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','3','AFQjCNFFK5xPcE_2Yl9D8NhHmBbb_Y8UJg','','0CDAQFjAC',null,event)">color - Pygame Documentation</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zXwLCILEH14J:www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html+&amp;cd=3&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','3','AFQjCNGwtfM-FoMMusa6z3-GjN68_lw5BQ','','0CDEQIDAC',null,event)">Cached</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href="/search?hl=en&amp;safe=off&amp;q=related:www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html+hlsa+hsva+rgba&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=S-WYUPKzGI7JmAWAr4CwBw&amp;ved=0CDIQHzAC">Similar</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS2" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="st">Color.<em>hsva</em> - Gets or sets the <em>HSVA</em> representation of the Color. Gets or sets the <b>...</b> Color.<em>hsla</em> - Gets or sets the <em>HSLA</em> representation of the Color. Gets or sets <b>...</b> Color.normalize - Returns the normalized <em>RGBA</em> values of the Color. Returns the <b>...</b><br></span></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc" sig="8Ft">  <div data-ved="0CDQQkgowAw">  <div data-ved="0CDUQkQowAw"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="http://softimage.wiki.softimage.com/sdkdocs/sicppsdk/html/classXSI_1_1MATH_1_1CColor4f.html" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','4','AFQjCNFu-Fgfc5DxRWUiz6rFQcmtu8VxQw','','0CDYQFjAD',null,event)">CColor4f Class Reference</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>softimage.wiki.softimage.com/.../classXSI_1_1MATH_1_1CColor4f....</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:a3m9eQIkVpcJ:softimage.wiki.softimage.com/sdkdocs/sicppsdk/html/classXSI_1_1MATH_1_1CColor4f.html+&amp;cd=4&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','4','AFQjCNE2tLroL_B4pfp_-yHsgN77HgygkA','','0CDcQIDAD',null,event)">Cached</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS3" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="st">Detailed Description. A color class represented by single floating values. CColor4f supports the <em>RGBA</em>, <em>HSVA</em> and <em>HLSA</em> color models.<br></span></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc" sig="E2M">  <div data-ved="0CDkQkgowBA">  <div data-ved="0CDoQkQowBA"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="http://api.call-cc.org/doc/imlib2" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','5','AFQjCNHJCEk0145qLjFUDow7uz6--d9ecQ','','0CDsQFjAE',null,event)">imlib2 | chickadee</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>api.call-cc.org/doc/imlib2</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:f3rEHKk7xdQJ:api.call-cc.org/doc/imlib2+&amp;cd=5&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','5','AFQjCNFIOeaytJwKaUCFahhv0rZYsCrtNA','','0CDwQIDAE',null,event)">Cached</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS4" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="st">Create a color specifier for the given <em>RGBA</em> values. (color/<em>hsva h s v a</em>) =&gt; color procedure. Create a color specifier for the given <em>HSVA</em> values. (color/<em>hlsa h l s a</em>) <b>...</b><br></span></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc" sig="QIQ">  <div data-ved="0CD4QkgowBQ">  <div data-ved="0CD8QkQowBQ"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/softimage2013/en_us/userguide/files/shaderpresets690.htm" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','6','AFQjCNEcMDDSe_MGltcAPZgdz_Xba5qhrA','','0CEAQFjAF',null,event)">Softimage User's Guide: Scalar Matte</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>download.autodesk.com/global/docs/.../en.../shaderpresets690.htm</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7EBn3t17As0J:download.autodesk.com/global/docs/softimage2013/en_us/userguide/files/shaderpresets690.htm+&amp;cd=6&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','6','AFQjCNH9A6Y1UtnSCaNB5fq9oEMv6l6dIQ','','0CEEQIDAF',null,event)">Cached</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS5" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="st">Determines which color model you will select a color from: <em>RGBA</em>, <em>HLSA</em>, or <em>HSVA</em>. Channel. Selects the color channel. You can only select from this parameter if <b>...</b><br></span></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc" sig="ziI">  <div data-ved="0CEMQkgowBg">  <div data-ved="0CEQQkQowBg"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="http://packages.python.org/python-igraph/igraph.drawing.colors-module.html" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','7','AFQjCNFXOQ9ZwDTXEYanvZb2l-be3NWrvg','','0CEUQFjAG',null,event)">igraph.drawing.colors.color_name_to_rgba</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>packages.python.org/python.../igraph.drawing.colors-module.html</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YiCWholHT38J:packages.python.org/python-igraph/igraph.drawing.colors-module.html+&amp;cd=7&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','7','AFQjCNE-O44T9i6KfHzrDu2_TN6q5khIDg','','0CEYQIDAG',null,event)">Cached</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS6" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="f">10+ items – </span><span class="st">Converts a color given by its <em>RGBA</em> coordinates to <em>HSVA</em> <b>...</b><br></span><table class="tsnip"><tbody><tr><td>hsla_to_rgba</td><td>l</td><td>1.0</td><td>Converts a color given by its <em>HSLA</em> coordinates (hue <b>...</b></td></tr><tr><td>rgba_to_hsva</td><td>b</td><td>1.0</td><td>Converts a color given by its <em>RGBA</em> coordinates to <b>...</b></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc" sig="ELy">  <div data-ved="0CEkQkgowBw">  <div data-ved="0CEoQkQowBw"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="http://xrvg.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/XRVG/Color.html" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','8','AFQjCNFa4U6Y0BceJtaHJrjPYBL9uluwiQ','','0CEsQFjAH',null,event)">Class: XRVG::Color</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>xrvg.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/XRVG/Color.html</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xzEzVZQqjlsJ:xrvg.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/XRVG/Color.html+&amp;cd=8&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','8','AFQjCNHAiQ1acFXS45OCe2dh8t04dv79Zw','','0CEwQIDAH',null,event)">Cached</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS7" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="st"><b>...</b> blue complement format255 g g= green grey hsl <em>hsla hsla</em> hsv <em>hsva hsva</em> hue <b>...</b> rgb2h rgb2hsl rgb2hsv rgb2sl rgb2sv <em>rgba</em> saturation svg value white yellow <b>...</b><br></span></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc" sig="AMw">  <div data-ved="0CE4QkgowCA">  <div data-ved="0CE8QkQowCA"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="http://pygame.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/color.html" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','9','AFQjCNFAhMqlvpl3nu5ke-K5EGXFjdObuA','','0CFAQFjAI',null,event)">pygame.Color — Pygame v1.9.2 documentation</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>pygame.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/color.html</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:y8n_BdkVwnMJ:pygame.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/color.html+&amp;cd=9&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','9','AFQjCNFUzsehzHw76YNkL-4oahK-n-JvIA','','0CFEQIDAI',null,event)">Cached</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS8" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="st">Color.<em>hsva</em>, —, Gets or sets the <em>HSVA</em> representation of the Color. <b>...</b> The Color class represents <em>RGBA</em> color values using a value range of 0-255. <b>...</b> The <em>HSLA</em>  components are in the ranges H = [0, 360], S = [0, 100], V = [0, 100], A = [0, 100].<br></span></div></div><!--n--></li><!--m--><li class="g"><div class="vsc">  <div data-ved="0CFMQkgowCQ">  <div data-ved="0CFQQkQowCQ"> </div>   </div><div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="vspii"><div class="vspiic"></div></div></div>   <h3 class="r"><a href="http://pypixel.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/pypixel.py" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','10','AFQjCNFn-7_0BAq_upcNihBWBYg3GediLg','','0CFUQFjAJ',null,event)">#!/usr/bin/python # # TODO # Thread pypixel so that the end user <b>...</b></a></h3><div class="s"><div class="f kv"><cite>pypixel.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/pypixel.py</cite><span class="vshid"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:-prP6iP75CAJ:pypixel.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/pypixel.py+&amp;cd=10&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=au" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','10','AFQjCNE0O_xZcdco81OFkgu3JTMawmr5LQ','','0CFYQIDAJ',null,event)">Cached</a></span></div><div class="esc slp" id="poS9" style="display:none">You +1'd this publicly.&nbsp;<a href="#" class="fl">Undo</a></div><span class="st">TODO # Write color wrapper for <em>HSVA</em>, <em>HSLA</em>, <em>RGBA</em> # import random as randy import pygame from pygame.locals import * # Screen size WIDTH = 640 HEIGHT <b>...</b><br></span></div></div><!--n--></li></ol>
```

Comment: I've tried to use this and it isn't working. I even made a span called st and it still wouldn't work. No errors that I can see as well

Comment: Okay, sorry about that - I should have made a fiddle from it. Have a look here for one: http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/YResM/ ('st' is the className of the spans in _my_ example - google's search results) - You'd have to change it to suit your own html. Does this help?